# No module named combo (from import wx.combo) - pyspread

Tags: python, linux, module, package

I am attempting to download [pyspread](https://manns.github.io/pyspread/download.html). The homepage lists a set of dependencies that need downloading which I do using conda. All this is fine, but when I try to run pyspread I receive the following error message:

```
>     Traceback (most recent call last):   
> File "/usr/bin/pyspread", line 191, in OnInit
>     from src.gui._main_window import MainWindow   File "/usr/share/pyspread/src/gui/_main_window.py", line 54, in <module>
>     from src.gui._toolbars import MainToolbar, MacroToolbar, FindToolbar   File "/usr/share/pyspread/src/gui/_toolbars.py", line
> 51, in <module>
>     from _gui_interfaces import ModalDialogInterfaceMixin   File "/usr/share/pyspread/src/gui/_gui_interfaces.py", line 52, in <module>
>     from _dialogs import DimensionsEntryDialog, AboutDialog   File "/usr/share/pyspread/src/gui/_dialogs.py", line 61, in <module>
>     from src.gui._widgets import PythonSTC   File "/usr/share/pyspread/src/gui/_widgets.py", line 56, in <module>
>     import wx.combo ImportError: No module named combo OnInit returned false, exiting...
```

It seems that I don't have the wx.combo module installed. I have tried reinstalling wxPython and nothing has changed. I can find the combo.py file if I type

`$ ls /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk3/wx`

but I'm not sure what that means. I am very new to Linux and don't yet have the background to unpick this. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`pip install --upgrade pyod`
[the result of this above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XsEN.png)

`Installing collected packages: combo, suod, pyod Attempting uninstall: pyod Found existing installation: pyod 0.7.7.1 Uninstalling pyod-0.7.7.1: Successfully uninstalled pyod-0.7.7.1 Successfully installed combo-0.1.0 pyod-0.7.9 suod-0.0.4`

above code will install combo, pyod, suod all in one if you have installed an older one it will remove that install  a newer version
for more info [click here](https://pyod.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html).

Comment: Hi Jeffery! Please familiarise yourself with [answering questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before writing your next one. Enjoy your stay at SO :)

Answer (score 1):

If your pyod is uptodate, install combo by:

`pip install combo`